# How do I create a PPA?

Tags: ppa

How do I create my own custom PPA to share with the Ubuntu community? I am trying to create my own custom package set and I would really like to share it with the community.

Comment: related or the same: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28562/how-do-i-create-a-ppa-for-a-working-program?rq=1

Comment: Maybe this helps http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/getting-set-up.html

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Using a Personal Package Archive (**PPA**), you can distribute software and updates directly to Ubuntu users. Create your source package, upload it and Launchpad will build binaries and then host them in your own apt repository.

- [Create a Launchpad Account](https://login.launchpad.net/+new_account).
- [Activate a PPA](https://launchpad.net/people/+me/).
- You can only activate a PPA if you have [signed the Ubuntu code of conduct](https://launchpad.net/codeofconduct).
- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)
- [Uploading your source packages](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading).

Here is a [detailed explanation](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA).

Comment: FWIW I was able to active my PPA before I signed the code of conduct.

Comment: This is the best answer.  You were just told how to create a PPA.  

The response below (by totti) is not a PPA, but it is a public repository.  The two are different, despite (potentially) accomplishing the same thing.  

He even says in the first line of his answer:
"This question has a well written, accepted answer.  As the OP wants a simple way to publish his packages I'm giving an easy hack."

Because you prefer the easy hack does not make it the best answer.

Comment: OK, but none of the links in this answer really describes how to do it from scratch. all links here are made for developers, that are already into the material much more

Comment: @rubo77 - the "how to create" is strictly too broad to be answerable.  It all depends what you are trying to package.  Indeed each of the steps in the above answer can be individual Q's with a good detailed answer each.

Comment: Totti's new answer is great already

Comment: Do I need to sign my software for ppa?

Comment: I would just add that you can create scripts that generate source packages from source repositories. This allows automating the process a bit. See: https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/SourceBuilds

Comment: This answer misses the step "create your source packages". Probably the hardest step.

Comment: The debian packages have to be source and not binary which is often a deal breaker.

Answer (score 107):

## How to create a .deb file

This is a tutorial on creating a basic .deb file from a given sample script. In this tutorial first we create a **sample program** in bash that just show 'HELLO FROM PROGRAM'. Then we create a **control file** for the program in order to make a debian installer. Finally they are packaged into a `.deb` file.

### Steps:

1. create a sample program in bash

   ```
   mkdir "$HOME/create_deb/pgmdir"
   gedit "$HOME/create_deb/pgmdir/zenity_hello.sh"
   ```

   paste the following code into it

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   echo 'HELLO FROM PROGRAM' | zenity --text-info
   ```
2. Make the program executable

   ```
   chmod +x "$HOME/create_deb/pgmdir/zenity_hello.sh"
   ```
3. Create control file for the debian package

   Make a file named `control` inside folder `DEBIAN`

   ```
   mkdir "$HOME"/create_deb/DEBIAN
   gedit "$HOME"/create_deb/DEBIAN/control
   ```

   and paste following details

   ```
   Package: hellodeb
   Version: 0.1
   Architecture: all
   Maintainer: totti
   Installed-Size: 6
   Depends: zenity, bash
   Section: testing
   Priority: optional
   Homepage: http://askubuntu.com
   Description: This is my first debian package.
    Guided by Totti Torvalds.
    In Description new line start with a space.
   ```

   You can edit the contents if you like. Read more about the format of this file [here](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html) and [here](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html).
4. Create `postinst` script, that is executed immediately after installation of the package

   ```
   gedit "$HOME"/create_deb/DEBIAN/postinst
   ```

   then paste

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   set -e
   echo 'Installing program : zenity_hello.sh ......' | zenity --text-info
   ```

   and make it executable

   ```
   chmod +x "$HOME/create_deb/DEBIAN/postinst"
   ```
5. Create `prerm` script, that is executed before removal of the package

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   set -e
   echo 'Removing program : zenity_hello.sh ......' | zenity --text-info
   ```

   and make it executable

   ```
   chmod +x "$HOME/create_deb/DEBIAN/prerm"
   ```
6. Make package structure and copy programs, data, etc..
   Create a structure of your installed programs and its data. In this example we put the file at `/bin`.

   ```
   mkdir -p "$HOME"/create_deb/bin
   cp "$HOME/create_deb/pgmdir/zenity_hello.sh" "$HOME/create_deb/bin/zenity_hello"
   ```
7. Build the *.deb* file.

   ```
   dpkg-deb --build "$HOME"/create_deb .
   ```

   The `.` will auto name the `.deb` file with version, arch etc. Or your custom name

   ```
   dpkg-deb --build "$HOME"/create_deb "$HOME"/create_deb/hellodeb.deb
   ```

   Or if you build the .deb file with

   ```
   debuild -k'your GPG key here' -S
   ```

   then you can upload it to Ubuntu Launchpad with

   ```
   dput ppa:<lp-username>/<ppa-name> packet-source.changes
   ```

   like described [here](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading) (source: [create a .deb Package from scripts or binaries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27715/create-a-deb-package-from-scripts-or-binaries/27731#27731))
8. Install the newly created `.deb` package.
   You can open it with `software-center` but it may not allow you to install. So I recommend to use `gdebi` package  manager.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gdebi

   gdebi "$HOME"/create_deb/hellodeb.deb
   ```

   Now you can install it. During installation you should see a *gtk dialogue*

   > Installing program : zenity_hello.sh ......
9. After installing open a terminal and type `zenity_hello`. If the program correctly installed and everything OK you should see a *gtk dialogue*

   > HELLO FROM PROGRAM
10. Removing package

    ```
    sudo apt-get remove zenity_hello
    ```

### Publish your repository in 2 minutes

As the OP wants a simple way to publish his packages I'm giving an easy hack.

requirement: dropbox (or anyother service, for ex. [github](http://github.com)) account with a public folder.

1. Create a folder inside your Public-Dropbox-Folder where you put your *.deb Files:

   ```
   mkdir ~/Dropbox/Public/deb-packages
   ```

   or create that folder somwhere else and put a symlink in your Public folder:

   ```
   mkdir ~/deb-packages
   cd ~/Dropbox/Public
   ln -s ~/deb-packages/ deb-packages
   ```
2. Go into that folder and create a script that, when executed, creates the Packages.gz, containing all the needed informationen about your deb-packages.
   create:

   ```
   gedit import.sh
   ```

   put this in it:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null |gzip > Packages.gz
   ```

   make it executable:

   ```
   chmod  x import.sh
   ```
3. Copy some *.deb Files into the Folder. Could be your own or some that aren't available through other repositories. Then go into the Folder and execute the script we put there:

   ```
   cd ~/deb-packages/ 
   ./import.sh
   ```

   That should create the so called **Packages.gz** File, which apt looks for to know which Packages are located at this repository.

---

### That's it

Now, wait for Dropbox to synchronize the Folder and grab the **Public-URL from the `Packages.gz`**. It should look something like this:

```
http://dl.getdropbox.../Packages.gz
```

Get rid of the end of that link, put some more words to it and you can now use and populate the following line for the sources.list:

```
deb http://dl.getdropbox.../deb-packages ./
```

That's it you got your own deb repository running. Always synchronized locally, but available to anyone, anytime, anywhere.

**NOTE:** `dpkg-scanpackages` is available from `dpkg-dev`
reference

Comment: +1 Great! this worked: I used Github and there the raw directory for a folder `releases/` see https://github.com/rubo77/mouse-speed/blob/master/release/mouse-speed.list

Comment: This describes a self hosted PPA, but how can I [Build a Ubuntu debian package](http://askubuntu.com/q/493666)

Comment: If you build the .deb file in step 7. with `debuild -us -uc -k'your GPG key here'` then you can upload it with `dput ppa:<lp-username>/<ppa-name> packet-source.changes` to Launchpad like [described here](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading) (source: [create a .deb Package from scripts or binaries](http://askubuntu.com/a/27731))

Comment: @rubo77,Thanks, I welcome you to add this infos at end of my answer.

Comment: OK, I just did, I also found out, that you need other parameters for Launchpad to not to create the .deb file right now (just -S): `debuild -k'your GPG key here' -S` because Launchpad will create the deb file (if it is not rejected) - what would the ` -us -uc` have been for?

Comment: `debuild -k'your GPG key here' -S` Complain about `debian/rules`

Comment: @rubo77 - I add `deb https://github.com/rubo77/mouse-speed/raw/master/release ./` to the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and run the command `$ sudo apt-get update`, but I got the following error: W: can't download https://github.com/rubo77/mouse-speed/raw/master/release/./Packages  HttpError404

Comment: try add this line `deb https://github.com/rubo77/mouse-speed/raw/master/release /` to a new file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mouse-speed.list` and run `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 2):

You will need a Launchpad.net account to create a PPA. Just click on your user on Launchpad (click on your name on the upper left) and create a PPA. You may have to first sign the Code of Conduct and have a GPG key registered with your account.

Answer (score 0):

PPAs are just repositories. `ppa://` URLs are just simple URLs that the script `apt-add-repository` converts to a `deb` line in a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, using Launchpad and obeying its demands. (I read the source code.)

**TL:DR: See bottom.**

---

*It’s just an attempt to gain power and control over us supposedly “dumb” “helpless” users, based on a toxic culture sold as “simplicity”, ultimately stemming from how Apple treats users, due to Steve Jobs having been a pathological control freak. (Sources: Books by people who did work directly under him.)

But this is your computer, so they have no power here. :)*

If you look at the `deb` lines, they contain the real repository URLs. E.g.

**deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/maarten-fonville-android-studio-jammy.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/maarten-fonville/android-studio/ubuntu jammy main**

And if you open that URL, you see a specific directory structure. That’s all the “magic”.
Now of course the easiest way, is to

1. create your local repository in a directory of your choice (home server, local pc, your homepage, etc), and
2. if it’s local, run a very simple httpd server (“web server”) to serve that directory to the target audience (e.g. you, your household, friends).
3. Then anyone who wants to use your repository, can just put your repository’s key (as a file) into his `/etc/apt/keyrings/`, and
4. add a text file to his `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, containing a `deb` line as above, but with your key and your url, as well as the correct architecture and version code name (e.g. jammy) of course.

In the long run, it’s probably easier to just have an extremely simple (one-liner?) script that takes any normal repository URL, and creates those files automatically, imitating apt-add-repository without going through the Launchpad gatekeepers.

This answer serves as the (previously missing) link that “ppas” are just repositories with a bit of “security” (mostly from you, instead of for you, as one might think), and so …

---

**TL;DR: The right question would be: How to create (and add) a repository?**

**Debian maintains a complete guide on how to do this:

https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/#Set_up_and_maintain_a_repository

E.g. using `reprepro`.**

*So you do NOT need a launchpad account, obey any master, NOR sign a code of <strike>conduct</strike> censorship, hate and reverse discrimination.*

*Of course, if you want to share it with entities that themselves prefer to obey and follow Canonical/Ubuntu/Launchpad, and refuse to trust anything else, and so will not use anything unless their masters have agreed that it is safe for them, then that is equivalent to dealing with their masters themselves. Who, as it stands, demand full obedience. (As in signing that CoC.) … I don’t bend over that low, so I cannot tell you how to do that.*