# How do I install the latest Blender 3D builds from a PPA?

Tags: ppa, blender

My problem is that i want to install latest blender and upgrade it automatically via `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` . So, i tried to add a repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cheleb/blender-svn 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blender
```

So, after the first line executed in terminal it gives me:

```
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 tag:launchpad.net:2008:redacted
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~cheleb/+archive/blender-svn
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

 Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options
 --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.pvnVePB2Fl --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80/ --recv tag:launchpad.net:2008:redacted
 gpg: "tag:launchpad.net:2008:redacted" not a key ID: skipping
```

And when i am running the second line it gives me:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cheleb/blender-svn/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch
http://ppa.launchpad.net/cheleb/blender-svn/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages
404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch
 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cheleb/blender-svn/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages
 404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
ones used instead.
```

**Q:** why this ppa does not work and what should i do to have blender updated automatically!?!Thanks

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50169/2843

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IF you *Actually click on the links* you can find out why, the address just doesn't exist.

And if you  go to the launchpad page: https://launchpad.net/~cheleb/+archive/blender-svn you can see it's not accessible.

@PhoneixS asked the maintainer of the PPA Ralf Hölzemer (cheleb) and he said:  ".*..cannot maintain that PPA any longer."*

---

You can however Install it from this other PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~thomas-schiex/+archive/ubuntu/blender

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thomas-schiex/blender
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blender
```

The builds are recent so you still get the newest Blender.

Here you can find Instructions on how to Compile Blender from SVN

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Doc/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu/CMake

Comment: Yes, but for how long? And why is this happening?

Comment: I don't know there is however another Blender PPA I'll add it.

Comment: Yes, I searched for another and i found this repository you mentioned. My problem is that i am not sure if this is the newest. How can i see that?

Comment: You can see that the most recent build was 8 days ago 2.63.1+svn49102 whereas the current SVN from the Blender SVN is Revision 49349 so it's not far behind. Of course the better option to keep blender updated is to compile it and install from SVN, although you'll have to that manually.

Comment: Could you please guide me with this manual install or should i create a new post? If i compile it how will i be able to upgrade it automatically? Thanks

Comment: I've only ever compiled something once, so instead of giving you something I will not be able to help you with, I'll redirect you to their wiki that has documentation. However that will not update blender automatically, that you will have to re do everyhting again, that is getting the newer source, recompile it, etc.

Comment: Ok, then why did you mention that the better option is to build it from svn? What are the advantages?

Comment: You get the latest Blender, and you do it whenever you can, instead of waiting for someone else to do it, that's why I also said you have to do that manually.

Comment: Ok then. Very helpfull information, thanks very much!

Comment: A last question! Is there any way to build it my own and then give it in a ppa for other people?Is there any guide that can help?thanks

Comment: You could create your own PPA for that purpose, [How do I create a PPA](http://askubuntu.com/questions/71510/how-do-i-create-a-ppa) or  just build deb files and keep them on a file storage service, such as Ubuntu one or Dropbox.

Comment: A little information of why is down.

I ask to Ralf Hölzemer (cheleb) and he said that he "...cannot maintain that PPA any longer." but he also mention to use irie PPA.

Answer (score 6):

And now  that Irie PPA is not updated anymore, to get the latest version (updated weekly), you can use this instead:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thomas-schiex/blender
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blender
```