# what are alternative program for ETABS?

Tags: software-recommendation, alternative

Hi I'm new to Ubuntu but i like it so much that i am telling all my friends to get rid of windows and start Ubuntu.But there is this problem : many of my friends are engineers and so they have to use "3D max" "ETABS" and "Autocad" i wanted to know if there is any alternative program like these? (i know about wine but I'm asking for any alternative)

Answer (score 0):

[DraftSight](http://www.3ds.com/products-services/draftsight/overview/) is the only application I know of at that level and even then, I'm certain it's not as thorough as some of the features in some of the AutoCad versions.

However, it is monetarily free (on all platforms) so that might be a swaying factor.

Answer (score 0):

[Blender](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169542/how-do-i-install-the-latest-blender-3d-builds-from-a-ppa) should be a very good replacement to "3D Studio MAX".

Have some example [movies](http://www.blenderguru.com/27-inspiring-blender-animations-that-will-make-your-jaw-drop/).