# Were is the Debian package for Blender 2.70a?

Tags: package-management, deb, blender

In the official repository of Ubuntu and Debian is only the 2.6 version of Blender. I searched with Google to find a Debian package to download. But I found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also [a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~irie/+archive/blender) mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169542/how-do-i-install-the-latest-blender-3d-builds-from-a-ppa) that you can use:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:irie/blender
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blender
```

It also has the `blender2.4` package, which is great for people like me who prefer it :-)

Answer (score 3):

Today I bundled a Debian package for Blender 2.70a.

http://finn-krauss.com/blender

At the moment it is only for 64bit architecture, but I'm working on it.
You can use GDebi to install it graphical. You install GDebi by entering `sudo apt-get
install gdebi`.

Answer (score 3):

**Ubuntu Mirror:**

Blender 2.70a For X86-64 = http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/blender/blender_2.70a-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb

Blender 2.70a For X86-32 = http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/blender/blender_2.70a-2ubuntu2_i386.deb

**Third Party Mirror:**

Blender 2.70a For X86-64 = http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/blender/blender_2.70a-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb

Blender 2.70a For X86-32 = http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/b/blender/blender_2.70a-2ubuntu2_i386.deb