# How to compile Blender on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: compiling, blender, cmake

I am just using ubuntu 14.04, and i want to compile blender with Cmake,
Here is the Website:http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu/CMake
When i already in the Cmake application, i configure it then it wont work.
i already have everything,
Can you explained to me.

Comment: which version of blender? is there a reason for not using the one included: aka using `sudo apt-get install blender`

Comment: Please be more specific than "it won't work". Add error messages or more specifics to the question.

Comment: but Mateo, using sudo apt-get install blender it's still 2.69 and i want the latest version of blender and if i download from the website it is just a file.

Comment: If you want the latest blender, you can add corresponding ppa. And install as you install any other software in ubunu

(Whatever you download would always be a file, what did you expect?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to read [this about alternative blender installs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169542/how-do-i-install-the-latest-blender-3d-builds-from-a-ppa/169546#169546).

The cmake name is a bit misleading, it actually configures options and creates the makefiles. Run `make install` in the build directory after you have run `ccmake`. Once make has finished you can then start blender with `./bin/blender` in the same directory.

If you are using the cmake-gui then you need to open a terminal in the `Where to build binaries` setting shown in the cmake-gui window.

Answer (score 0):

issue this to install upstream libraries

```
sudo apt-get build-dep  blender
```

then in the blender source directory issue

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..  # <-- NOTE the two periods (..) which tells cmake to look in parent dir
make
make install
```

now you can launch

```
source_dir/build/bin/blender
```

optionally add to $PATH

```
export PATH=$PATH:source_dir/build/bin
```

then launch using

```
blender
```