# Contributing to Ubuntu packages

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm using the SFML library which - wasn't at all tedious but - took about 30 minutes to get it configured properly. Now the library is available using `apt-get`, but it installs an earlier version.

Is there any way for me to contribute the newer version of the library to Ubuntu repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

1. Use a PPA to provide your package. This is probably the easiest and fastest way. See https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA and [How do I create a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71510/how-do-i-create-a-ppa)
2. Check if Debian already [provides](http://packages.debian.org) a newer version of the package. If so, it usually will be available in the next major version of Ubuntu.
3. Contact the maintainer of the Ubuntu package and offer your help
4. Contact the maintainer of the Debian package and offer your help
5. If the package is not in Debian, you can also try to maintain the package. If you get the package in Debian sid (unstable) it usually will be part of the next major version of Ubuntu. This will take of course some time as the new maintaincer process can be time-consuming. See also http://mentors.debian.net/intro-maintainers and http://mentors.debian.net/