# Unable to install specific package version with apt-get

Tags: apt, software-installation

I am trying to run the following command to install a specific version of libssl:

```
apt-get install libssl1.0.0=1.0.1-4ubuntu5.13
```

As of right now, the latest version is `1.0.1-4ubuntu.14`, but I want the earlier version until I can do some testing with the new one. However I get the error:

```
"E: Version '1.0.1-4ubuntu5.13' for 'libssl1.0.0' was not found
```

If I run the same command for `1.0.1-4ubuntu5.14`, it works. So, I figure maybe I need to add a repository in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, but I don't which repository might have what I need, or what entry to make.

Comment: You can download .deb of `libssl1.0.0_1.0.1e-3ubuntu1_amd64` for ubuntu 14.04 from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/libssl1.0.0/1.0.1e-3ubuntu1) or [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/main/base/libssl1.0.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older Packages are pruned from ubuntu repo's and not kept around. You can either install from the [debs directly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line), but if you want to do this in an apt-aware way your best bet is to [create a local repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170348/how-to-make-my-own-local-repository)  in a folder on your system, place your deb's there, make your apt sources aware of the local repo, and then install the specific version.

The other option is to [create your own ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71510/how-do-i-create-a-ppa) on launchpad servers and then you will be able to pull that directly from any computer (Warning: Debian packaging is relatively straightforward, but still requires knowledge of linux and a little bit about coding/building software).

It is also possible to add to your sources the repos for most recent version of ubuntu (or debian) that has the package you want, install it, and then remove the source. The disadvantage of this is that the package may be replaced in a future apt-get unless you take advantage of [pinning](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences)

Comment: Installing from a deb will make it `apt`-aware, since `apt` relies on `dpkg`, and `dpkg` is aware of debs installed from anywhere. The bigger issue is that `apt` will ask you to upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: @saiarcot895 It is aware, but it will not pull dependencies for you.

Comment: Aware that it is installed that is

Comment: For the dependencies (assuming they can be met), that would just be `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: @saiarcot895 Well TIL, but a local repo is pretty easy to set up and if you are going to be pulling a lot of debs it makes it really easy to manage them, for instance, if you compile a custom version and replace it in the local repo folder, it will upgrade without complaining.