# How to provide a ppa for a project on Github in README?

Tags: apt, git, github

I have uploaded the source on Github but I want to provide the PPA in the README file so that users can directly do

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:foo/project
```

Then update the cache using:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the package using:

```
sudo apt-get install project
```

versus making and biulding the source.

[This site](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser) can be used as reference. They have provided a PPA in README.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/71510/how-do-i-create-a-ppa)