# What's the "right thing to do" when latest version of some gnu software is not available via apt-get

Tags: upgrade, versions, ddrescue

I run Ubuntu 16.04 and need to use ddrescue from the gddrescue package. (NB: this is NOT the same software at all as dd_rescue from the ddrescue package). The latest version available via apt-get is 1.19, and the latest version available via apt-get for ANY version of ubuntu is 1.22. However, the latest version available from gnu.org is 1.23, and I would like to run the latest version. My questions are:

1. I have no problem to build the latest version from ftp.gnu.org/ddrescue/ddrescue-1.23.tar.lz, but once I do, is there some way to install it on my system so that apt-get "knows" about it? For example, if 1.20 appears in some repository I use, I would not like apt-get to "upgrade"  to this, etc.
2. Would it "decent/correct/good/nice" of me to turn my build of this software into an apt-get installable package and contribute it to the appropriate repositories? I can't imagine that it's all that difficult to do, though I CAN imagine that it might be a bit fiddly and that for security reasons, random unknown users are not in general allowed to upload upgrades of established software packages.

If this is a contribution which is allowed, could someone point me to a. the official directions for producing an apt-get package? and b. the official directions for submitting that package?

I run Ubuntu 16.04, but I'll bet that ddrescue builds identically for any distro that's based on the same debian as that version of Ubuntu. Should I be trying to contribute a package for that debian?

Thanks

Comment: I'd probably separate the 2 questions here in 2 different questions on askubuntu, but maybe you could look at this for the 2nd question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1345/what-is-the-simplest-debian-packaging-guide#

Comment: Also see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/71510/how-do-i-create-a-ppa

Answer (score 2):

You can build it from source using checkinstall, read this wiki page for details: https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall

TL;DR checkinstall creates a .deb package, which you can then uninstall either via apt or dpkg.