# How do I update something in the Ubuntu repository?

Tags: 12.04, package-management, repository

All of my google results on this question are about just learning to use `synaptic`.

I've noticed that Ubuntu's `TTYtter` package is quite a ways behind. `TTYtter` is just one file (one `perl` script) so even a newb like myself could update the Ubuntu repository without any complications of patching folders or `.tar.gz`'s or the like.

So I think I can, and I'd like to, fix `TTYtter` to the more recent version. But how do I go about that?

Comment: Even if you can update it, will you have done all the necessary testing to ensure it won't adversely effect other parts of the system?  Just thinking out loud here, because I am not sure how much testing is done by Ubuntu people, and then, there are other repos you might add that will introduce other untested stuff too.

Comment: @ubnewbie2 It's just one perl script and it works with the default version of `perl` in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initially do Read this [Packaging/ SourceBuilds/ GettingStarted](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/SourceBuilds/GettingStarted) guide

First Create a [Launchpad account](https://launchpad.net/)

Then proceed to [**ttytter Packaging branch**](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ttytter) , then Select the Version of Ubuntu you want to Contribute to .

Contact the [“Ubuntu branches” team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches) for Uploading your version to [**ttytter Packaging branch**](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ttytter).

Create your [**New source package recipe - Precise for Example**](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/precise/ttytter/precise/+new-recipe)

**NOTE** : I am assuming they would allow you , otherwise as [con-f-use](https://askubuntu.com/users/17789/con-f-use) in the above [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/170315/63025) mentioned , create your [own PPA](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA) , then [Upload your package to PPA](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading).

---

other Useful Links

[How do I create a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71510/how-do-i-create-a-ppa)

[How do I create a PPA for a working program?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28562/how-do-i-create-a-ppa-for-a-working-program)

[Complete Ubuntu Packaging Wiki Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete)

Answer (score 3):

That is true with almost all applications in the Ubuntu repositories: They lag behind in their versions. The reason is that Canonical usually checks the packages for security and compatibility with Ubuntu. Also someone has to [build the .deb](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/SourceBuilds/GettingStarted) package and upload it to the repository. That adds an extra step and slows things down but increases the quality and feel of Ubuntu.

That being said, you can't update the main repository. All you can do is create your own ppa on [launchpad](http://www.launchpad.net) and hope people use it. Lauchpad has good introductory guides on how to do that. You could also get in touch with Canonical and propose your new build.

If you want to "update" `TTYtter` only locally on your system, you're free to do so but the next update in the main repositories might override your changes with yet another outdated version (which might break your configuration). To prevent that you should put updating on hold `sudo aptitude hold ttytter` ([more info](https://askubuntu.com/a/18656/17789)).

Comment: The "hold" should not be necessary if one sticks to the build rules and integrates the version info properly. Unless specifically told so (configuration-wise or via command line), a newer package should not be replaced by an older one.

Comment: In my last paragraph, I was talking locally, meaning manually replacing the files not using a package/ppa.

Comment: Oh -- OK, I thought you refered to [CheckInstall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CheckInstall) -- which by the way would be another approach.