# create PPA source package from existing .deb package

Tags: ppa, packaging, deb

i wanna modify some files in .deb package and upload it to my PPA,
is that possible and how to ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/28562/how-do-i-create-a-ppa-for-a-working-program

Comment: http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/fixing-a-bug-example.html

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.

A binary Debian package contains built binaries only and there is no way to retrieve sources from binaries as a lot of information is lost during the process.

If you were to edit only data that are not modified by the compilation process (say configuration files for instance) then you would be able to generate a new .deb file from the old one. **However**, you will *not* be allowed to upload this one to your PPA for safety reasons. All the packages in the PPA's **must** be compiled on the servers sandboxes to prevent malicious modifications of packages. It does not prevent people from possibly building dangerous Debian package, but at least it *guarantees* that the provided binaries are really the output of the source code compilation process.

Comment: Hi. What if I don't want to upload package to a repository, but want to rebuild it with different configs (e.g. to share it localy). Do you know how to do it? Maybe you could give some hints, bcause now I even don't get how to search for it