# Publishing my first application on PPA (Launchpad)

Tags: application-development, ppa, launchpad

Let's say that I have a little script that outputs `"Hello world!"` in terminal:

```
echo "Hello World!"
```

How can I publish it to Launchpad PPA so I can type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:myusername/hello-world && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hello-world
```

Then running `hello-world` in terminal the application will output `"Hello World!"`.

I read the instructions from [this page](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/apps/other-forms-of-submitting-apps/ppa/), but the image is blurry for me...

Comment: So, you're basically asking, "How do I package a shell script"? If so, you could take a look at this: [How do I create a PPA for a working program?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28562/how-do-i-create-a-ppa-for-a-working-program)