# how do i create a ppa for a package made by someone else but not managed anymore

Tags: apt, updates, package-management, ppa, launchpad

Okay ,

1st of all, though ive used PPAs for all these years, i never went into the details of how they are created and managed and stuff...

so, i am a noob at being on the "creator" or " manager" side of PPA.

now,

i have a Samsung Laptop and there was always a ppa that provided some packages that enabled use of the fn keys for various operations like wireless enable/disable etc etc...

but there are no signs of this ppa being updated anymore for 14.04...

I downloaded the .deb packages from the launchpad page.

so, can i create a new ppa only having the .deb packages?
If yes, how?

If no, can i do get anything else also from the current launchpad page and make a ppa?

A detailed answer would be awesome as ive never created any ppa nor do i know how they are managed! >_<

The Launchpad page for the ppa i am talking about can be found [HERE](https://launchpad.net/~voria/+archive/ppa)

ThankYou!

Comment: much of your question is covered by this http://askubuntu.com/questions/28562/how-do-i-create-a-ppa-for-a-working-program?rq=1  - can you narrow your question down to an area that is not covered by the linked Q&A?

Comment: okay ill check it out... currently in exams... will close this question if all of that helps in some days... sorry for the delay.. @fossfreedom