# Help creating source packages for launchpad

Tags: packaging, launchpad

I want to upload the first version of my app to launchpad. Launchpad requires a source package of the app.

My app is written in C, it compiles with gcc and generates one binary. How can I create a source package for my app? (Ubuntu documentation on this matter is outdated unfortunately.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a PPA for a working program?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28562/how-do-i-create-a-ppa-for-a-working-program)

Comment: What documentation is outdated???  I've uploaded packages via PPA & used the current documentation (*very little has changed with regard packages for decade+ actually unless you're talking snaps which you aren't*!)  https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Uploading  is current for example as current releases use the *Ubuntu 9.10 and later*, ie. `dput`

Comment: I mean the ubuntu documentation is kinda outdated. For example bzr dh-make is no longer working. @guiverc

Comment: If you provide URLs to the documentation that you believe needs to be corrected, we may be able to update it; otherwise raise a ticket on the page and it'll get corrected  (`dh_make` is a package & is it's own command; not part of bazaar)

Comment: @guiverc This one needs updating: https://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html

Comment: I don't think that's an update issue; but a regular error/typo, and needs a ticket to fix

Comment: Reported here - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-packaging-guide/+bug/1944501  (feel free to leave comment; amend or click "affects me to" as appropriate)

Comment: @guiverc So, what is the alternative to this erroneous command? `dh_make` without the bzr start?

Comment: Sorry I can't help there; maybe helpful - https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2249679.html